# Is there a better way to fetch table data which are more than 20,000?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

I'm recently trying to use selenium(Chrome driver one) to get some data in a web. Normally the table shows up to 30 with multiple page, but I changed an argument of it, so It can show me up to 30,000 now.

The problem is, when I use my code to fetch data, it took too long time for it.
I divided it with multiple pages with 2000 data per page, but still it took too long.

This is the code I used to get data

It took about 3? 5? minute when I tried to get 1000 data.

```
texts = [t.text for t in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='datagrid_class']/div/table[@class='table1']/tbody/tr/td")]
```

I just want to check if anyone has better idea for this.

Thank you for your kind advice in advance!
Thank you!

Comment: I think that's the standard approach for selenium. I've read that it could be faster if you extract the entire page in one go with beautifulsoup before parsing the page offline but have never really tried it

Comment: @kerwei Thank you Kerwei! yes. I thought so as well. The problem is, I can't use Beautifulsoup cuz the page which needs some interacting to browse it. (the page url which doesn't have any parameters in it...)

Comment: If it's loaded by ajax then I don't think you have much of a choice. You may try to check out multiprocessing I suppose. Or a quick dirty way is to run your script in different sessions i.e. multiple browsers. I did something similar a few years back and just waited it out patiently while the computer does its job :)

Comment: Problem is solved or not yet

Comment: @kerwei That's what I'm thinking now ! I'm considering the dirty way as well haha.

Comment: @akshaypatil Hi Akshay. Well, not yet. I hoped there would be a good way to get data fast, but as Kerwei said, I don't have much choices so... haha.
If you have any advice for codes, I'm happy to learn it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use JavaScript to get data much faster, try code below:

```
texts = driver.execute_script('return [...document.querySelectorAll("div.datagrid_class table.table1 tbody tr td")].map(e=>e.textContent)')
```

Also you can find some more examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54264476/python-selenium-get-all-href-attributes/54264621#54264621) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52481091/how-can-i-get-values-from-selenium-webelement-more-than-faster)

Comment: Oh my! Actually I'm not familiar with Javascripts so I had no idea of considering it ! Thank you for your great advice Sers! And also examples! You are truly my life saver !