# How to perform selenium automation of an auto refreshing web page (every 5s)?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm automating a web page consisting of a very large table (300+ rows) using Chrome. The table content gets refreshed every 5 seconds. Before selenium finishes traversal of all the rows, the table gets refreshed. For example, if selenium had traversed 50 rows and then the table got refreshed, the 51st row throws a StaleElementReferenceException.
I am unaware of which capabilities need to be modified in order to fetch content.

I have tried disabling javascript and running the automation script. However, disabling of javascript has led to problems with chrome driver.

```
def table_get():
    header_list = list()
    return_list = list()

    head = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('thead')
    body = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('tbody')

    for row in head.find_elements_by_tag_name('tr'):
        for header in row.find_elements_by_tag_name('th'):
            header_list.append(th.text)

    for row in body.find_elements_by_tag_name('tr'):
        temp_list = list()
        for cell in row.find_elements_by_tag_name('td'):
            temp_list.append(cell.text)
        return_list.append(zip(header_list, temp_list))

    return return_list
```

Expected Output: Traversing all the rows and returning list of dictionaries, where each dictionary key is the header and value os the row content under the header.

Actual output: Traversal unable to complete. StaleElementReferenceException thrown in between of traversal.

Comment: So basically, if I understand right, what you're looking for is a way to grab all the table's data within 5 seconds right?

Comment: Not really. In my opinion, capturing such large tables data within 5 seconds using selenium might not be possible. Disabling the auto-refresh functionality on the webpage could be a possible solution.

Comment: Yes, disabling it is a possibility. Although you might need to consider the implications of disabling the refresh -- you'll be working with outdated data. Is that okay for your use-case? If so, are you able to isolate what is refreshing the table, so that we can find a solution to disable it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Javascript to get data like in example below, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54264476/python-selenium-get-all-href-attributes/54264621#54264621), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52481091/how-can-i-get-values-from-selenium-webelement-more-than-faster) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54397039/edit)

```
headers = driver.execute_script('return [...document.querySelectorAll("thead tr th")].map(e=>e.textContent)')
cells = driver.execute_script('return [...document.querySelectorAll("tbody tr td")].map(e=>e.textContent)')

for header in headers:
    print(header)

for cell in cells:
    print(cell)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using filefox, go to `about:config` and set `accessibility.blockautorefresh` to true. Now copy your firefox profile... menu-> help-> troubleshooting information and copy the profile directory path.

Set your firefox profile in python

```
profile_directory = webdriver.FirefoxProfile("your/copied/path")
driver = webdriver.Firefox(profile_directory)
```

For chrome, copy [this](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/auto-refresh-blocker/nmhmgghfmjjoejobimppckbalonobkck?hl=en) url and paste it [here](https://crxextractor.com/) and get the .crx file. Once you have obtained the crx file, do this in python:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
options = webdriver.chrome.options.Options()
options.add_extension("/path/to/autorefreshblocker.crx")
capabilities = options.to_capabilities()
driver = webdriver.chrome(desired_capabilities=capabilities)
```